# How load getStoreConfig option as a code for use in phtml?

Tags: configuration, template

I want to load the option saves the admin panel and use as configuration loading and being inserted into my custom.phml, but the two ways I tried not work, as I proceed? thank you.

1. `<? php echo Mage :: getStoreConfig ('customizefooter / option / custom_html_code'); ?>`
2. `<? php echo {{config path =" customizefooter / option / custom_html_code "}}; ?>`

Comment: How do you set the config for customizefooter/option/custom_html_code ?

Comment: Hi, Fooman. I have set this
http://pastebin.com/WwKsq09L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem..... 
`<? php echo Mage :: getStoreConfig ('customizefooter / html_options/ custom_html_code'); ?>`, works, thanks for noob help.